# why is the flag 'i' not increasing in my code

Tags: java

I was building a simple racing game with java applet but it is not working properly
and even after multiple dry runs I dont see any mistake in the code.
why is the variable 'i' not increasing in my code...

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.applet.*;
 import javax.swing.JApplet;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 /*
 <applet code= "car.class" height=1000 width=2000>
<param name="my" value="opp1_car.png">
<param name="you" value="opp2_car.png">

 </applet>
 */

 public class car extends Applet implements KeyListener,Runnable
 {  int x=0,y=0,x1=0,a=50,i=0;
Image car,car_opp;
int width,height,width_op1=0,width_op2=0;
Thread t;

public void init()
{   
    addKeyListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.gray);       
    this.requestFocus();
    Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    width= (int)(dim.getWidth())/2;
    height=(int)dim.getHeight();                
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{           
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(0,0,600,1000);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(1400,0,600,1000);

    car_opp = getImage(getDocumentBase(),getParameter("you"));
    g.drawImage(car_opp,width+width_op1,i,this);            //      this is not moving 



    car = getImage(getDocumentBase(),getParameter("my"));    //     this moves on LEFT or RIGHT keyEvent
    g.drawImage(car,width+x,700,this);      

    String s="("+width_op1+",x="+x+",y="+y+")";
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString(s,200,500);        
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int k=e.getKeyCode();
    switch(k)
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:  if(x>-360 ) x=x-20; break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: if( x<340 ) x=x+20; break;          
    }
repaint();      
}

public void start()
{
    t = new Thread();
    t.start();

}

public void run()
{   

    while(true)
    {   Random random= new Random();
        try
        {

            i=i+50;
            t.wait(100);

            if(i>1000)
            {
                i=100;
                width_op1=random.nextInt(340 + 360 + 1) -360;
                width_op2=random.nextInt(340 + 360 + 1) -360;
                width_op1=200;
            }           
            repaint();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        /*if((i>680&& i<780) && (x < width_op1+50 && x>width_op1-50))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }*/
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}   
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}



}
```

Comment: It seems you didn't execute the `run()` method to increment `i`. (I post this as comment because I didn't test this)

Comment: `catch(Exception e){}` Never, ever, ever, ever do this. When you do this, if there is *any* exception, you don't have the slightest *idea*. *At the very least* do `e.printStackTrace();` so you at least *know* about it. Never, ever just put a block of code where you eat all exceptions. You should always catch the most specific exception that you can (`InterruptedException` in this case?). Just putting an empty catch block for all exceptions is one of the worst things you can possibly do while writing a program.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how Threads work. In order to run a Runnable in a Thread, you must pass it into the constructor and then run the Thread.

Try this:

```
public void start(){
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();

}
```

Comment: All I wanna do is to bind 2 opponent cars in two threads n thus i cannot actually use the main thread....but I am stuck with the 1st car here...